# Aligning a html table to center issue in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, html-table, center

My table structure is as follows:

```
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 cols=17 border=0 id="table" width="1250" >
<colgroup>
    <col width=0>
    <col width=45>
    <col class="coldroup_3">
    <col class="coldroup_3">
    <col class="coldroup_3">
    <col class="coldroup_3">
    <col class="coldroup_3">
    <col class="coldroup_3">
    <col class="coldroup_3">
    <col class="coldroup_3">
    <col class="coldroup_3">
    <col class="coldroup_3">
    <col class="coldroup_3">
    <col class="coldroup_3">
    <col class="coldroup_3">
    <col class="coldroup_3">
    <col class="coldroup_3">
</colgroup>
<tbody>     
    <tr>
            ......
            ......
```

My css for the class coldroup_3 is

```
.coldroup_3{
    width: 70px;
}
```

Here based on some conditions I am showing and hiding columns, for example if I need to show only five columns then I am hiding remaining columns using JQuery show() & hide() methods.

Problem is, here I am trying to center the table using CSS on that table

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

here hided columns are also taking those 70px width which I have set using CSS, so the columns which I am displaying are not aligning to the center.

Note: Problem is only in Firefox, remaining browsers are fine.

Any help on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

After doing a little reading on your issue, you could probably just make..

```
   .colhidden {
       width: 0px;
   }
```

Then in your same jQuery calls you are using to .hide() / .show(), use .removeClass and .addClass() function to add/remove class... so

```
   $('bla').removeClass('coldroup_3').addClass('colhidden');
```

http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/